# Phonegap Error - "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin."

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

New to phonegap, having difficulty even after reading all the SO posts on the subject, just can't get this working.

I have the org.apache.cordova.whitelist plugin installed, I have added the Content-Security-Policy meta directive in my index.html file, and I have added the appropriate  and  and  tags in my config.xml.  However, every time I run the app (android) I receive the following error:

> "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using
>   the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source:
>   file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js

Here is the very basic index page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Copyright (c) 2012-2014 Adobe Systems Incorporated. All rights reserved.

    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src: 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <link href="jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquerymobilejquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.login.test" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>LoginTest</name>
    <description>
        Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon gap:platform="webos" src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1136" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="^4.0.2" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 4):

**For testing purposes only**: Comment out this line ->

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src: 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />`

Than your Problem is gone.

You can find some additional information about whitelisting here: [Cordova Plugin - Whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist)